# Required package `emacs-24' is unavailable

Tags: helm, package

I use DropBox to share my .emacs and .emacs.d with the various machines I use.  I setup helm using emacs on my mac but now I'm having issues when opening emacs on my Linux box:

```
Warning (emacs): Unable to activate package `helm'.
Required package `emacs-24' is unavailable
Warning (emacs): Unable to activate package `helm'.
Required package `emacs-24' is unavailable
Warning (initialization): An error occurred while loading `/home/gibson/.emacs':

File error: Cannot open load file, helm

To ensure normal operation, you should investigate and remove the 
cause of the error in your initialization file.  Start Emacs 
with the `--debug-init' option to view a complete error backtrace.
Warning (emacs): Unable to activate package `helm'.
Required package `emacs-24' is unavailable
```

I also get "Package 'emacs-24' is unavailable" when I try to M-x package-install helm

Comment: Maybe try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16177807/js2-refactor-from-melpa-package-emacs-24-1-is-unavailable

Comment: That did it.  Thanks.  I upvoted your comment, but I don't know how to mark a question as answered.

Comment: Mike: As we can't close questions as duplicates if the duplicate is on a different site, nanny (or yourself) could add an Answer with the same information, and you can then mark that answer as Accepted.

Comment: @phils Sure, that sounds good.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> The reason for this can be a lingering old version of `package.el` in your load path.  `package.el` was officially included in GNU Emacs 24, and the downloadable file for earlier Emacs versions doesn't support dependencies on built-in packages (`emacs-24.1` is considered a built-in package here).
>
> Type `M-x locate-library RET package` to find where Emacs is getting its `package.el` from. The path it shows should end with `lisp/emacs-lisp/package.elc`. If it doesn't, try getting rid of the indicated file (or changing the load path so Emacs doesn't find it).

From: https://stackoverflow.com/q/16177807/1279369

Comment: I have the questioner's problem, and just to whoever's interested, this answer didn't work for me.  My package matches the given string.  I don't say this as a complaint but just an FYI that there must be multiple causes of this warning.