# Error installing "Package 'emacs-24.3' is unavailable"

Tags: package

I'm running emacs 24.4.1.  Like the title says.  When I run 
`M-x package-install RET flycheck`  I get the message

Package 'emacs-24.3' is unavailable

Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16177807/js2-refactor-from-melpa-package-emacs-24-1-is-unavailable

Comment: Duplicate of http://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/10691/227